# How to retrieve closed form of a recursion

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form, recursion

I am looking for a closed form of this recursion:

$$T(0)=1$$

$$T(n) = 
\begin{cases}
T(n-1) & \text{for odd } n \\
2^n+T(n-2) & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

Obviously this recursion leads to something like this: $$T(6) = 2^0+2^2+2^4+2^6$$
Which would be the same like this: $$T(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor} 2^{2i}$$

How do I elemninate the sum now? Is there any other way to retrieve the closed form?

Btw, the solution is: $\frac{4^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor + 1}-1}{3}$

But looking for the way to get there.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $2^{2i}=4^i,$ and the sum is the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: The closed form of $T(n)$ is :
$$T(n) = \dfrac{4}{3} 2^{2 \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} - \dfrac{1}{3}$$

Comment: How embarrassing. Thanks for the hint. Sometimes it is time for a break.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let :
   $$x_n = T(2n)$$
   Show that :
   $$z_n = \dfrac{x_n}{4^n} - \dfrac{4}{3}$$
   is geometric.
2. Deduce a closed form of $T(2n)$.
3. For the closed form of $T(n)$ notice that :
   $$\left\lfloor \dfrac{2 p}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \dfrac{2 p + 1}{2} \right\rfloor$$